# How to implement Pagination for YouTube Data API V3 in iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, youtube-api

I'm building an iOS app using Youtube data API which fetches playlist of a channel and display it in a tableview.But the problem is I was able to get only max 50 playlist results.But actual number of playlist is more than 100.When I googled about it I found that to get additional result pagination should be done.How I can add pagination in iOS app for displaying entire playlist in a table view.If I want to use nextpage token to make another request then how should I make it and which part of the code should be modified.I use API key instead of OAuth

ViewController Code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
   
    

    @IBOutlet weak var coursesTV: UITableView!
    
    var a = [Item]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        coursesTV.delegate = self
        coursesTV.dataSource = self
        
        Playlist.sharedObj.getPlayList { (i) in
            self.a = i
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 self.coursesTV.reloadData()
            }
           
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        
        return a.count
           
       }
       
       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
           
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        {
            cell.textLabel?.text = a[indexPath.row].snippet!.title!
            
            return cell
        }
        
        return UITableViewCell()
        
        
       }
}
```

NetworkService struct

```
import Foundation

public  struct Playlist
{
   public static let sharedObj = Playlist()

    let playlistuRL = "URL_HERE"
    
    
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    
    
    func getPlayList(onSuccess:@escaping([Item])-> Void)
    {
            let task = self.session.dataTask(with: URL(string: self.playlistuRL)!) { (data, response, error) in
                    
                    do
                {
        
                        let item = try JSONDecoder().decode(RootClass.self, from: data!)
                        
                        print(item.items!.first!.snippet!.title!)
                        
                        onSuccess(item.items)
                    }
                    
                    catch
                    {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                }
                
                
                task.resume()
        
    }
}
```

Model struct

```
import Foundation


public struct RootClass: Codable {

        public var etag : String!
        public var items : [Item]!
        public var kind : String!
        public var nextPageToken : String!
        public var pageInfo : PageInfo!
        
}


public struct Default: Codable {

        public var height : Int!
        public var url : String!
        public var width : Int!
        
}

public struct High: Codable {

        public var height : Int!
        public var url : String!
        public var width : Int!
        
}

public struct Item: Codable {

        public var etag : String!
        public var id : String!
        public var kind : String!
        public var snippet : Snippet!
        
}

public struct Localized: Codable {

        public var descriptionField : String!
        public var title : String!
        
}

public struct Medium: Codable {

        public var height : Int!
        public var url : String!
        public var width : Int!
        
}

public struct PageInfo: Codable {

        public var resultsPerPage : Int!
        public var totalResults : Int!
        
}


public struct Snippet: Codable {

        public var channelId : String!
        public var channelTitle : String!
        public var descriptionField : String!
        public var localized : Localized!
        public var publishedAt : String!
        public var thumbnails : Thumbnail!
        public var title : String!
        
}

public struct Standard: Codable {

        public var height : Int!
        public var url : String!
        public var width : Int!
        
}


public struct Thumbnail: Codable {

        public var defaultField : Default!
        public var high : High!
        public var medium : Medium!
        public var standard : Standard!
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to implement load more concept for tableview. When you reach last row in table, make api request. Youtube API provides NextPageToken and PreviousPageToken in response.So, you can make api request using NextPageToken when you reach last row.

Example code snippet:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text=[self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (indexPath.row ==[array count] -1 ) { //this method will get called when you will scroll to the bottom of your table view 
    [self sendAPIRequestMethod];  } return cell; }
```

Comment: Ok then how can I add next page token to the url

Comment: playlists API supports pageToken parameter. So, construct url like  https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?channelId=UCrA&maxResults=50&key=AIZsk&pageToken=CBkQAA

Comment: Ok then how to update token value for each page in url